# WeakReference of a Collection in java

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

**Backstory**

In a library that I maintain we have an internal map keeping track of our cache.
Users of the library are interested in having list access to this map, however we can only provide this by copying its contents (thread-safety reasons).
The idea is to cache this list when it is first accessed without having much memory overhead on a second access.
To illustrate:

```
List<Bob> list = cache.asList();
List<Bob> otherList = cache.asList(); // use from cache, if still available
```

The problem is, we don't want to keep this list forever if its not needed anymore. Since java uses GC we thought it would be appropriate to use a `WeakReference` for this, to allow using it if its not collected.

**Question**

If I have a `WeakReference<List<Bob>>` stored inside my class, what happens if one of the elements becomes weakly reachable (which implies the list is weakly reachable)? Is it possible that the GC decides to just collect the element inside the list or would it look for all other weakly reachable objects referencing it and also collect them, in this case the list?

The problem would be, if the GC collected an element of the list and we then try to access the list again (if thats even possible) what would happen?

**Clarifications**

I'm not interested in the reachability of the list, I know that the list is inside the `WeakReference` and that the elements are irrelevant to its reachability. I care about a specific state, in which both the list and an element of the list are weakly reachable and whether it is possible that the GC only collects the element but not the list itself. What exactly does the GC do in this specific scenario?

Comment: The elements inside the list are entirely irrelevant to the reachability of the list itself.

Comment: I'm sorry if its not clear, I'm not asking about the reachability of the list specifically. I'm interested in the behavior of the GC on the elements of the list itself

Comment: @Minn why you can't make an experiment?

Comment: Your list is in the WeakReference, not the elements.

Comment: @vlad324 I'm not sure how I would test whether a specific behavior is *possible*.

Comment: @Minn you have `WeakReference` for list, not for it elements, so GC can collect list itself or nothing.

Comment: Note that the clearing of a weak reference is a separate action from actually being garbage collected. When weak references are cleared, their referents are made finalizable, and finalizers are allowed to republish the object and prevent it from being collected. ([Example.](https://ideone.com/Ca65Hw)) Objects need to actually be unreachable to be garbage collected. ([See *Reachability* section.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html))

Comment: Shouldn’t the `Bob` instances be referenced by your internal map anyway? So a weakly reachable `Bob` instance would imply that your `List` is outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the List itself is not weakly reachable its elements will not be either. (Assuming the list implementation itself does not use weak references or similar)

So there is no problem with having the list cached with a weak reference because it would either be garbage collected completely or not at all.

Comment: Oh, so the list inside the weak reference acts as a strong reference to its element? So the GC would collect the List and thus make the elements weakly reachable, correct?

Comment: Yes the list is still strongly referencing its elements. The elements are not necessarily weakly reachable just because the list is GC'd though. The elements may still be individually strongly referenced by some other object. If the list is the only strong reference to its elements though they will probably all (list and elements) be GC'd in one go.

Comment: Thank you, this really clarified how the transitive reachability works in this case and I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

In provided case (`WeakReference<List<Something>>`) you have only such possible scenario:

```
public class Test {

    private WeakReference<List<String>> listWeakReference;

    public Test(final WeakReference<List<String>> listWeakReference) {
        this.listWeakReference = listWeakReference;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> testList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

        Test test = new Test(new WeakReference<>(testList));

        // Initial check
        System.out.println(test.listWeakReference.get());

        // Call gc and check
        System.gc();
        System.out.println(test.listWeakReference.get());

        // Remove reference and call gc
        testList = null;
        System.gc();
        System.out.println(test.listWeakReference.get());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `SoftReference` is better for caches, and even that isn't very good.

`WeakReference` may be released **immediately** the reference becomes weakly reachable. However, it might not do that until sometime into execution - i.e. it doesn't happen during extensive testing, but it does in production. Fun times. NetBeans used to do this in its caching of files. Of course the rest of the code was expecting the caching so grabbed and released references with incredible frequency. After sometime using the application it would suddenly hammer file I/O and become unusable.

For best performance you need to explicitly estimate how much memory the process is using and release as necessary. Not easy.

Back to the question. Collection of contents of `WeakReference` (and `SoftReference` is a two phase operation. The first phase just clears the `Reference` (and queues if you are using that). The associated memory is not collected. The memory may be resurrected through a finaliser. The `WeakReference` is forever cleared and queued, it does not reset. Only when an object is completely unreachable can the associated memory be collected as a separate phase.

Fear not, Java is *memory-safe* (bugs excepted).

Comment: `Reference` objects to the same object are always cleared at once. Everything else would be a violation of the contract, as being cleared by the garbage collector implies that the referent is unreachable, not that some other `Reference` objects could still resurrect it. Only finalizers are an exception to this rule, as they are a legacy older than the Reference API. But by the time, a finalizer is executed, all soft and weak references which existed prior to the finalization are cleared.

Comment: @Holger I don't think that's true. I don't think there such a claim in the specification. Being cleared means that the referred object is only weakly reachable, and we're agreed that there exists at least one mechanism to go back from weakly reachable to strongly reachable. Dereferencing a weak reference is one way to go from a weak reference to a strong reference. Further, there's no lock on weak reference access - so every GC implementation would need to (do the equivalent of) a stop the world every time it cleared a `WeakReference`, which seems unlikely.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html): “Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in time that an object is weakly reachable. At that time **it will atomically clear all weak references to that object** and all weak references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references.” And yes, that implies that the clearing must happen during the stop-the-world phase, unlike enqueuing which may happen “at some later time”…

Comment: @Holger Oh. Forcing stop-the-world isn't great (I wonder if they all do).

Comment: Well, the main objective is to find reclaimable memory and by the time, an object’s memory is considered reclaimable, no references to it must exist. If that can’t be proven, e.g. because there may be reference objects pointing to it from memory not scanned, a garbage collector may decide to simply not clear any of them. In either case, having an excessive amount of reference objects may reduce the performance. The same applies to objects with nontrivial finalizers, as in case of HotSpot/OpenJDK, they are implemented as special reference objects as well.